# R: choose and replace a specific character to the middle of string

Tags: r, data-processing

I have a dataset looks like:

```
Name            Age
C_G06_M_15-35   55-64
C_G07_M_15-35   45-54
C_Pili_M_36-44  35-44
C_G14_M_15-35   55-64
C_Pili_M_15-24  45-54
C_Pili_M_25-35  55-64
C_G05_M_15-35   45-54
C_G01_M_15-35   35-44
C_G11_M_15-35   18-24
C_G20_M_15-35   25-34
C_AL006_A_15-60 45-54
C_ALL_F_15-35   35-44
C_South_M_15-24 25-34
```

But I only need "G13", "G10" etc. strings in the middle of "name" column, how to choose and replace it?

```
Name    Age
G06     55-64
G07     45-54
Pili    35-44
G14     55-64
Pili    45-54
Pili    55-64
G05     45-54
G01     35-44
G11     18-24
G20     25-34
AL006   45-54
ALL     35-44
South   25-34
```

Comment: In the `ALL_F_15_35` and `AL006_A_15-60` why you need the whole string except the `C_`?  This would extract the middle part though I am not sure whether it is a typo or not . `sub('[^_]+_([^_]+).*', '\\1', df1$Name)`

Comment: (untested) `lapply(strsplit(x$Name, "_"), "[", 2)`.

Comment: @akrun Sorry, I don't need _F_15_35 and _A_15-60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df1$Name <- sub('[^_]+_([^_]+).*', '\\1', df1$Name)
df1
#    Name   Age
#1    G06 55-64
#2    G07 45-54
#3   Pili 35-44
#4    G14 55-64
#5   Pili 45-54
#6   Pili 55-64
#7    G05 45-54
#8    G01 35-44
#9    G11 18-24
#10   G20 25-34
#11 AL006 45-54
#12   ALL 35-44
#13 South 25-34
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("C_G06_M_15-35", "C_G07_M_15-35",
"C_Pili_M_36-44", 
"C_G14_M_15-35", "C_Pili_M_15-24", "C_Pili_M_25-35", "C_G05_M_15-35", 
"C_G01_M_15-35", "C_G11_M_15-35", "C_G20_M_15-35", "C_AL006_A_15-60", 
"C_ALL_F_15-35", "C_South_M_15-24"), Age = c("55-64", "45-54", 
"35-44", "55-64", "45-54", "55-64", "45-54", "35-44", "18-24", 
"25-34", "45-54", "35-44", "25-34")), .Names = c("Name", "Age"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: It works,but why couldn't I using `df1 <- read.table(text = "IName            Age C_G06_M_15-35   55-64", header = T)` ?

Comment: @JefferyChen If this is in connection with the data structure showed in my post, it is first read with `read.table/read.csv`.  then `dput(df1)` gives the output in the format I showed.  It is also convenient for testing.  The data you showed can have columns either 'factor' or 'character' class, which we may need to guess.  But, if you show the dput output, we get the structure and easier to understand

Comment: Can I use this method to.csv file?[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx9mdGvx6TsZNDNqa3BsQmFTUTA/view?usp=sharing)
Sorry and thanks, I'm new in R

Comment: The method is used for small dataset to show as an example.  For large data, the output would be really big.

Comment: This dataset have a lot amount of data, how could I do?

Comment: Just use `read.table/read.csv` to read the data.  The one I mentioned is just for reproducibility.